# Decode HTML entities for ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I've got a string with HTML entities, and need to decode it on the level of the controller for it to display correctly in an input. Is there an equivalent of ng-bind-html on the controller level?

```
$scope.create.name = 'Tobias&#39;s team from &#34;Prague&#34;';

<input type="text" ng-model="create.name" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to use ngSanitize which use  to parser html.

```
 <script src="angular.js">
    <script src="angular-sanitize.js">
```

then include sanitize module in your app

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
```

refer : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize